# Any ideas how to transate OSQA?

Tags: translate, osqa

I just installed OSQA and now I want o translate in my language, I edited django.po file with poedit but something happens, sometimes words appear translated, sometimes not.

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's too late but here is a tip, using rosetta:

http://meta.osqa.net/questions/11183/where-do-i-find-italian-rosetta-language-pack